# Map where key returns value and value returns key

Tags: dictionary, key

Is there any sort of programming construct similar to a map where the key would return the value but the value would also return a key?

My use case is mapping status codes to status text, so basically what I want to do is this

```
KeyToKeyMap StatusCodes {
    200: "Ok",
    201: "Created",
    404: "Not Found"
}

StatusCodes[200] == "Ok"
StatusCodes["Ok"] == 200
```

Basically, if you use the numerical key, it will return the text and if you use the text, it will return the numerical status code.

Do any languages have this feature? Maybe I'm overthinking things.

Comment: in python: `bidict`: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bidict

Comment: okay! So what I'm looking for is called a bidirectional map. Makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: For this project, I'm using Groovy and it looks like Google Guava has one implemented